# jQuery / JS: Dynamically replace string if it matches a timestamp or specific pattern (##:##:##)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is: How do I dynamically replace a string if it matches a timestamp or specific pattern (using jQuery or plain JS)?

The pattern is: `00:00:00` **("0" being any numeral)**

What I'm doing is taking content from a div & stripping the content's HTML tags (using jQuery's `.text()` function), and I'd like to add new line breaks after every timestamp that is found in the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
For your specific pattern, a working regular expression would be `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d`. These `\d`s mean "digit". You can then use JS's `String.prototype.replace` function to add a line break after each timestamp.
In the below example, `$&` refers to the matched timestamp.

```js
const str = 'Some text 23:05:24 oh look more timestamps 10:93:20 test';

const regex = /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/g;

const replaced = str.replace(regex, '$&\n');

console.log(replaced);
```